# Switch case where I want to do some things if case A OR B and other things if case A XOR B?

Tags: javascript

Look at this switch case statement. Cases 'response' and 'error' have a lot in common, but also one line that tells them apart.

```
            switch (data.type) {
                case 'response':
                    const transactionId = data.trans_id;
                    const callbacks = commandCallbacks[transactionId];

                    if (!callbacks) {
                        if (logger) logger(`Dropping received message that was not requested, transactionId: ${transactionId}`);
                        break;
                    }

                    clearTimeout(callbacks.timedOutTimer);
                    callbacks.resolver(data);
                    break;
                case 'error':                
                    const transactionId = data.trans_id;
                    const callbacks = commandCallbacks[transactionId];

                    if (!callbacks) {
                        if (logger) logger(`Dropping received message that was not requested, transactionId: ${transactionId}`);
                        break;
                    }

                    clearTimeout(callbacks.timedOutTimer);
                    callbacks.rejecter(data);
                    break;
                case 'information':
                case 'progress':
                default:
                    break;
            }
```

How can I simplify this code?

Answer (score 1):

```
        switch (data.type) {
            case 'error':
            case 'response':
                const transactionId = data.trans_id;
                const callbacks = commandCallbacks[transactionId];

                if (!callbacks) {
                    if (logger) logger(`Dropping received message that was not requested, transactionId: ${transactionId}`);
                    break;
                }

                clearTimeout(callbacks.timedOutTimer);
                 data.type === 'response' ? callbacks.resolver(data) : callbacks.rejecter(data);
                break;
            case 'information':
            case 'progress':
            default:
                break;
        }
```

Additionally, if you have more options to check in switch you could change it to `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Use bracket notation and the conditional operator to access the appropriate function property on `callbacks`, and then call the function:

```
switch (data.type) {
  case 'response':
  case 'error':
    const transactionId = data.trans_id;
    const callbacks = commandCallbacks[transactionId];

    if (!callbacks) {
      if (logger) logger(`Dropping received message that was not requested, transactionId: ${transactionId}`);
      break;
    }

    clearTimeout(callbacks.timedOutTimer);
    const fn = callbacks[data.type === 'response' ? 'resolver' : 'rejecter'];
    fn(data);
    break;
    // ...
```

Note that if the function depends on `this` being `callbacks`, use `.call` instead:

```
fn.call(callbacks, data);
```

This doesn't really have anything to do with OR and XOR though - the different `case`s are all mutually exclusive, after all.

Answer (score 1):

Let the `response` case "fall through" to the `error` case by moving your `case` statement:

```js
switch (data.type) {
  case 'response':
  case 'error':
    const transactionId = data.trans_id;
    const callbacks = commandCallbacks[transactionId];

    if (!callbacks) {
      if (logger) logger(`Dropping received message that was not requested, transactionId: ${transactionId}`);
      break;
    }

    clearTimeout(callbacks.timedOutTimer);
    if(data.type === 'response') {
      callbacks.resolver(data);
    } else if(data.type === 'error' {
      callbacks.rejecter(data);
    }
    break;

  case 'information':
  case 'progress':
}
```

Comment: Tricky but awesome! :-)

Comment: it does not work with two same case checks. the first controls the flow. the later same cases does not work, because you are already falling through - until break, theis ends the switch and does not allow to return for checking.

Comment: it works only for the first same case, but not for the later one. it falls through.

Comment: @NinaScholz Ah, I think I see what you mean, thanks for clearing that up :)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a function for getting the callbacks and call this later with an object with right target values.

```
function getCallbacks({ trans_id }) {
    const callbacks = commandCallbacks[trans_id];
    if (!callbacks) {
        if (logger) logger(`Dropping received message that was not requested, transactionId: ${transactionId}`);
        return;
    }
    return callbacks;
}

switch (data.type) {
    case 'response':
    case 'error':
        let cb = getCallbacks(data);
        if (!cb) break;
        clearTimeout(cb.timedOutTimer);
        cb[{ response: 'resolver', error: 'rejecter' }[data.type]](data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd skip the switch statement altogether and write it like this:

```
if (["reponse", "error"].includes(data.type)) {
    const transactionId = data.trans_id;
    const callbacks = commandCallbacks[transactionId];
    if (callbacks) {
        const callback = {
            response: data => callbacks.resolver(data),
            error: data => callbacks.rejecter(data)
        }[data.type];
        clearTimeout(callbacks.timedOutTimer);
        callback(data);
    } else if (logger) {
        logger(`Dropping received message that was not requested, transactionId: ${transactionId}`);
    }
}
```

Generally I prefer using objects to switching.

Answer (score 0):

This is my best attempt:

```
            switch (data.type) {
                case 'response':
                case 'error':
                    const transactionId = data.trans_id;
                    const callbacks = commandCallbacks[transactionId];

                    if (!callbacks) {
                        if (logger) logger(`Dropping received message that was not requested, transactionId: ${transactionId}`);
                        break;

                    }
                    clearTimeout(callbacks.timedOutTimer);

                    switch (data.type) {
                        case 'response':
                            callbacks.resolver(data);
                        case 'error':
                            callbacks.rejecter(data);
                    }

                    break;
                case 'information':
                case 'progress':
                default:
                    break;
            }
```